# Smarty Error: failed to open stream: Permission denied'

Tags: php, smarty, wampserver

I am creating a site using PHP and Smarty as template engine, so far I am still working on a local enviroment (wampserver). The problem is that one of 5 times I load a template page I get a error, if I refresh I get the page normally, but this is a problem, I can't get this error this often. The error is this:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include(C:\wamp\www\network_italiaChannel\templates_c\%%66^666^666FBF6C%%amministratore_editvideo.tpl.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in 
>       C:\wamp\www\network_italiaChannel\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1264
>
> ErrorException: include(C:\wamp\www\network_italiaChannel\templates_c\%%66^666^666FBF6C%%amministratore_editVideo.tpl.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\network_italiaChannel\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1264

Comment: I think you need to investigate your permissions

Comment: @Toby Allen Since i am using windows it cant be, anyways i took a look at the permissions and it seems that is set to full control

Comment: Its not permission you are correct. However that directory name does not look legal. i.e. this one `%%66^666^666FBF6C%%amministratore_editVideo.tpl.php`  so I assume you are not processing a parameter correctly.